# Why use <scope>test</scope> for cucumber dependency?

Tags: maven, cucumber, testng, pom.xml, cucumber-jvm

After Selenium, testNG, I just started using Cucumber and Maven. First I created a cucumber project without using `<scope>test</scope>` for dependency. Like this:

```
<dependency>
     <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
     <artifactId>cucumber-java</artifactId>
     <version>7.5.0</version>
</dependency>
```

But I had a problem. The changes I made in the step definitions were not being applied without building the project. With some research I added this `<scope>test</scope>` for cucumber. And the problem was solved. (This is also how I resolved a classpath error I got for testng.)

**But how does adding scope test make a difference? Why are we adding it?**

Comment: Scope `test` means that your dependency would be included into class path when you do `mvn test`. IDE normally also integrate that aspect with their code assistance and validation features. So that since test are executed against compiled app, you would "see" your main code and other libs main code from your tests but you would not "see" test code from your main code.

Comment: @AlexeyR. Thanks for your answer. I would like to clarify my question a little more. My src > main > java folder is completely empty. I just use src > test. If the scope is not written and by default it applies to the whole project, why does it make a difference to write a scope test?

Comment: You'd have to explain a bit more about the tool that you're using. Sounds like it may be malfunctioning.

Comment: @barisonr https://www.baeldung.com/maven-dependency-scopes